# Get/Set not getting triggered for Attribute in Custom Component

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have an attribute within a custom component, but it doesn't appear to be calling any get/set methods regardless of how I format either the attribute (specifying assignTo) or writing the get/set code itself. I've double checked this with the Debug Logs and it simply does not get called. This is what I have (I've simplified it as much as possible, the actual final implementation won't have static content

Apex Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Invoice__c"  showHeader="false" renderas="pdf">
    <c:Invoice_PDF_HTML_Content invoiceId="a0pO0000000lBcP" />
</apex:page>
```

Apex Component:

```
<apex:component access="global" controller="Invoice_Quote_Controller" >

    <apex:attribute access="global" name="invoiceId" description="Invoice ID" type="String" />

    <!-- HTML-->
</apex:component>
```

Controller:

```
global without sharing class Invoice_Quote_Controller {
    private String invoiceId = null;

    public String getInvoiceID(){
        system.debug(invoiceId);
        return invoiceId;
    }

    public void setInvoiceID(String InvoiceId){

     system.debug(InvoiceId);
     system.debug(invoiceId);
     if(this.invoiceId==null){

        this.invoiceId = InvoiceId;
        // Constructor code
    }
}

//Blank Constructor
global Invoice_Quote_Controller() {

} 
}
```

I've got the getter and the setter for invoice_id inside Invoice_Quote_Controller. It just never gets called, what am I doing wrong? (Is it something to do with the global scope?)

Comment: Have you tried another scope? Seems odd that it wouldn't call the setter after instantiation of the controller.

Comment: Just tried making it public and it still doesn't appear to work :/

Comment: Can you post the controller too?

Comment: Sure, give me a few mins to edit. EDIT: Edited the question to include the controller

Comment: What happens if you put a debug line in the constructor? I just remembered having something weird happen with these before, but it was a while ago and I don't recall exactly what it was!

Comment: I think the problem is your assignTo="{!invoice_id}" does not match your get/set methods in your controller have you tried assignTo="{!InvoiceID}"

Comment: Sorry Andrew, that was my mistake when posting the code. The version I'm trying doesn't have assignTo used (edited the main post). I tried putting in "system.debug(invoiceId);" in the constructor and it reported that invoiceId was null, anything else you want me to debug in the constructor? Also, using assignTo with the same name as the attribute generates an error saying you can no longer do that.

Comment: You will need to apply an assignTo to bind it to a controller variable, otherwise it can only be referenced from the component markup itself.

Comment: Take a look at the docs for it here, http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_attribute.htm

Comment: Here is a better example, http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_comp_cust_elements_controllers.htm

Comment: Hey Andrew, want to post it as an answer and I'll mark it? I think that was the issue, when I was playing around with assignTo earlier, I may have had some things backwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to assign the values of Visualforce Components to variables in your controllers you need to apply the assignTo attribute, as per the [docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_attribute.htm) this is described as referencing...

> A setter method that assigns the value of this attribute to a class variable in the associated custom component controller. If this attribute is used, getter and setter methods, or a property with get and set values, must be defined.

The [docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_comp_cust_elements_controllers.htm) also show this example which helps illustrate its use...

> Similar to standard Visualforce pages, custom components can be associated with a controller written in Apex. This association is made by setting the controller attribute on the component to your custom controller. You can use the controller to perform additional logic before returning the component's markup to the associated page.

```
public class myComponentController {

  public String controllerValue;

  public void setControllerValue (String s) {
    controllerValue = s.toUpperCase();
  }

  public String getControllerValue() {
    return controllerValue;
  } 
}
```

The component markup looks like this...

```
<apex:component controller="myComponentController">
  <apex:attribute name="componentValue" description="Attribute on the component."
                  type="String" required="required" assignTo="{!controllerValue}"/>
    <apex:pageBlock title="My Custom Component">
      <p>
        <code>componentValue</code> is "{!componentValue}"
        <br/>
        <code>controllerValue</code> is "{!controllerValue}"
      </p>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    Notice that the controllerValue has been upper cased using an Apex method.
</apex:component>
```

You can also utilise the short hand notation for [properties](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_properties.htm), which can also include code to execute.

```
public class myComponentController {

  public String controllerValue {get; set; }

}
```

Finally keep in mind the order the setter methods are called is none deterministic, so don't have properties with dependencies. I know this is the only way if you want some kind of construction logic, just handle with care.

Glad to be of help! :-)